# FLEX : avoid memory leaks

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, memory-leaks

If in a component I have basic `Button` which can propagate `MouseEvent.CLICK` like this :

```
<s:Button id="btn" click="someFunction(event)" />
```

Should I manually remove this event if I remove my component with `parent.removeElement(myButton)` function or is it automatically removed ?

Thanks for clarification

Comment: Of course it will automatically removed. no need to remove manually.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is this the same if I listen event with `addEventListener()` function ? Or shold I use weak reference ?

Comment: same as `addEventListener()`

Comment: Thanks again ! I saw that if I use `Timer`, I have to use `removeEventListener` to avoid memory leaks, is it true ?

Comment: Once you set `timer = null` it should be ready for garbage collection. In smaller projects in most cases it makes no diferenece. In bigger ones it porpably will make difference. But, Personally, In my code, I would still remove the listener.

Comment: Ok. I think your confusion solved. So, i will post it as a answer so, it will help to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will automatically removed event once you remove component(Button). There is no need to remove event manually then.

**For Timer:**

Once you set `timer = null` it should be ready for garbage collection. In smaller projects in most cases it makes no difference. In bigger one it probably will make difference. But, Personally, In my code, I would still remove the listener.